# codeigniter anchor: problems with twig

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig, anchor

i am using twig 1.35.4 and codeigniter 3.1.9 in a webapp.
The following code:

```
Items: {{ anchor ('#', 'x', array( 'class'=> 'myclass') ) }}
```

fails with the following error. Am i doing something wrong or is a twig problem?

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: Twig_Error_Syntax
>
> Message: A parameter name must be a string, "Twig_Node_Expression_Constant" given.
>
> Filename: C:\www\ht\application\views\character\main.twig
>   Line Number: 11
>
> Backtrace:
>   File: C:\www\ht\application\third_party\Twig-1.35.4\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php
>   Line: 376
>
> Function: parseArguments
>
> File: C:\www\ht\application\third_party\Twig-1.35.4\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php
>   Line: 162
>   Function: getFunctionNode

Comment: Why do you have `{{ {{`? Maybe `{{` is enough?

Comment: sorry a typo, i corrected the code example, still the error remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig syntax for arrays is not `array('class'=> 'myclass')`, it is json-like:

```
{'class':'myclass'}
```

So, rewrite your string as:

```
Items: {{ anchor ('#', 'x', {'class':'myclass'}) }}
```

Comment: It works. code:You can see {{ anchor ('#', items|length , {'class':'myclass'} ) }} items on the ground.